# laravel resource passing multiple params for each item issue

Tags: laravel, eloquent, resources

i want to send 2 instance of model to 1 eloquent resource

`CheckTicketResource::collection($cardProducts)->additional(['gate' => $gateInstance]);`

using **additional** can not help me cause i can't use $gateInstance on each item of $cardProduct

could you help me ?!

Comment: Can you please explain more? What is your input? and what are you expecting as a result?

Answer (score 1):

Custom collection may help your situation.

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-collections#custom-collections